# CLLocation stops in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, background, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to send my position with iOS and swift, but after a while the application is stopped and stops working.

```
    class Location:NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
private var errorLocation: Bool = false
private var stuffLocation: CLLocation!

var outSocket: OutSocket!
var timer: NSTimer!
var stuff: Stuff!

override init() {
    super.init()
    outSocket = OutSocket()
    setupLocation()
}

func setupLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.Fitness
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if !errorLocation {
        errorLocation = true
        locationManager.allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled(10, timeout: 50)
        stuffLocation = locations[0]
        if timer == nil {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: #selector(Location.sendDataToServer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
}
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError error: NSError?) {
    errorLocation = false
}
```

This is my code, if anyone has done something similar or know how to prevent the APP stops will appreciate it.

Comment: The application stops receiving GPS information, since each event update GPS control that data for TCP socket to my server. I read that iOS stops background applications are, but do not know much about it.

Comment: The application stops when I leave the application itself. For example when I go to Facebook or simply when locking the device.

Comment: The time it takes to close is approximately 3 to 5 hrs. Sometimes mejos an hour. But this does not happen if I connected the dispositovo to the Mac.

Comment: without internet (or ) data is not possible. if app  is in suspended state every 500 m radius  coordinate change occur at the time we are try to update the location. but not accurate location get. which is used to achieve "startSignificantMethod"

Comment: You know some form of cachar errors that cause?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to keep getting GPS location updates while it is in the background you have to add an entry to the `UIBackgroundModes` array in the app's info.plist, and then you need to ask the user for permission. Do a search in the Xcode docs on `UIBackgroundModes`. Specifically look at the `location` value.

You will also need to make a case to Apple that you app should be allowed to use the GPS from the background when you submit the app to the app store.

Note that you are going to drain the user's battery in a hurry if you keep the GPS on at all time, AND a TCP socket in order to upload the coordinates.

Comment: Permits you mention and was added to the above application, but for some reason continue to be arrested.